# Unable to connect to php and mysql on raspberry pi

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am a newbie to PhP. I have just installed apache2 and php5 environment in raspberry pi.
I have created a database testdatabase and trying to connect to the database from php script. Here is my code

user enters email and password

```
<html>
<body>
<form action='action.php' method="post">

Email: <input label="email" type="email" name="email" required="required"/>
<br>
Password: <input label="password" type="password" name="password" required="required"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the script insert data into table

```
    <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("'localhost'",pi,"pwd","testdatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO users (email, password)
VALUES
('$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Whenever i click on submit i get the error

local host can not handle this request http error 500
( i can login to database using mysql -u pi -p )

I tried accessing phpinfo and it is working fine

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Please guide me where am I doing wrong?

Now I am just trying to see if the connection is successful or not

```
<?php 
 /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */ 
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin"); 
 // Check connection 
 if($link === false)
 { die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error()); } 
 // Print host information 
 echo "Connect Successfully. Host info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link); 
 ?>
```

It gives the same message. I can not even connect to the db. Do I need to set some environment variable?

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","pi","pwd","testdatabase"); remove single quotes

Comment: `mysqli_connect("'localhost'",pi,"pwd","testdatabase");` what does `pi` stands for?

Comment: @Mohammad pi is mysql user

Comment: how did you make sure your mysql database is set up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","pi","pwd","testdatabase");
```

remove single quotes

Comment: you might want to use if(isset($_POST['submit']){} then run your query and add name="submit" in your input type submit

Comment: added a code just to check the connection and getting the same error with this code as well.

Comment: you are mixing mysql and mysqli ,you should use mysqli try avoiding mysql

Comment: @iogan where should i add if(isset($_POST['submit']){} ?? sorry I am a newbie

Comment: first make proper mysqli connection

Comment: Hi @IOGAN even this new code is giving me the same error. Do you think I am missing some configuration somewhere?  simple phpinfo page is working and i can connect to db from the command line. Please see the your code that I tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171450/discussion-between-logan-and-prem).

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue on files plus some code level issue because finally I was able to run the code provided by @IOGAN. As of now I changed the permission of all the files to 777 ( it was 770 ) will do hit and trial for the minimum allowable file permission.

Comment: 777 is not the ideal permission for anything. 775 or 755